# Center a button on a UIToolBar

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I need to center the B item with respect to the toolbar. I create the following in the interface builder:

[image: Item B in the center]

It works fine until I dynamically insert additional items:

[image: Item B not in the center]

How can I maintain the centralized position of the B item? One idea was to use the Fixed Space Bar Button Items, but I couldn't, because the length of the toolbar changes as well (for different orientations).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this every time the tab bar change the size:

```
//lets be tabBar the big view and buttonB the.. well, button B
[buttonB setCenter:CGPointMake(tabBar.frame.size.height/2, tabBar.frame.size.width/2);
```

Comment: A UIBarButtonItem is not a UIView and has no `center` property. Your code will not work.

Comment: wow.. sory, it's because UIToolbar and UINavigationBar is so I thought this was too.